# Vorticity form of Euler equation: What about harmonic part?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose the co-closed 1-form $\eta$ is a solution to Euler's equation on a domain with non-trivial harmonic 1-forms (say the 2-torus; let's leave boundaries out of this). Let $\eta = \psi + h$ where $\psi$ is the co-differential of an appropriate 2-form and $h$ the harmonic part. We have$$\dot\eta + \mathcal{L}_{\eta^\sharp}\eta = dp.$$Using the fact that $\mathcal{L}h=0$ (modulo exact 1-forms) I can split this up as$$\left(\dot{\psi}+\mathcal{L}_{\eta^\sharp}\psi\right)+\dot{h}=d\tilde{p}$$where $\tilde{p}$ now absorbs the exact term due to $\mathcal{L}_{\eta^\sharp}h$. Now let me consider the vorticity form of the Euler equation, i.e., hit it with a $d$ and let $\omega=d\eta=d\psi$. Then I cannot seem to distinguish between$$\dot\omega + \mathcal{L}_{\eta^\sharp}\omega=0$$and$$\dot\psi+\mathcal{L}_{\eta^\sharp}\psi = d\tilde{p}.$$That would seem to suggest that $\dot{h}=0$. In other words harmonic components are invariants of Euler flows. That just doesn't seem right. On the other hand if the vorticity form of the Euler equation is correct for non-trivial domains I don't see how you could ever recover the harmonic part (if present, say, in the initial conditions) from the usual Helmholtz-Hodge recovery of $\eta$ from knowledge of $\omega$ unless any initial harmonic component stays invariant. While a harmonic $\eta$ by itself will stay invariant there seems to be no reason that should be true for $\eta$ which has a non-trivial co-exact component aside from a harmonic part. What am I missing?

Comment: Why must ${\mathcal L} h$ vanish?

Comment: In the specific case of the 2-torus, it appears that momentum conservation will keep the harmonic component of $\eta$ fixed, but this seems special to the $2$-torus.  It may well be that one cannot write the Euler equations purely in terms of the vorticity for more general compact domains, but one must instead consider a coupled system between the vorticity and the harmonic component.

Comment: I was sloppy. $\mathcal{L}_{(.)}h = d\iota_{(.)}h+\iota_{(.)}dh$ only vanishes modulo exact 1-forms (since $dh=0$ by assumption). Working modulo exact 1-forms is too ingrained in my thinking...

Comment: I think the ultimate answer to my question is that the vorticity form of the Euler equation simply contains no information regarding $\dot{h}$. That does not imply that $\dot{h}=0$. So to go from vorticity back to velocity one needs information about the circulation along generators of the homology. By Kelvin's theorem those are themselves advected though their circulation stays constant of course. That provides the additional information to turn knowledge of $\omega$ back into $\eta$.